# Grails dbm-update fails: MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, database-migration, spatial

I use Grails Database Migration. In my latest database update I created the following table:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

class City {

  String id
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated
  String name


  static constraints = {
    id maxSize: 16, unique: true
    name nullable: false, blank: false
  }


  static mapping = {
    id generator:'assigned'
  }


  def setIdIfMissing() {
    if (!id) {
      String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
      MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")
      byte[] digest  = sha1.digest(uuid.getBytes())
      def tmpId = new  BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16)
      id = tmpId[0..15] // size of the id
    }
  }

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  City() {
    setIdIfMissing()
  }

}
```

I created the changeset with `grails dbm-gorm-diff Update4.groovy -add`. Which is

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "mg (generated)", id: "1437215773652-1") {
        createTable(tableName: "city") {
            column(name: "id", type: "varchar(16)") {
                constraints(nullable: "false", primaryKey: "true", primaryKeyName: "cityPK")
            }

            column(name: "version", type: "bigint") {
                constraints(nullable: "false")
            }

            column(name: "date_created", type: "datetime") {
                constraints(nullable: "false")
            }

            column(name: "last_updated", type: "datetime") {
                constraints(nullable: "false")
            }

            column(name: "name", type: "varchar(255)") {
                constraints(nullable: "false")
            }
        }
    }

    changeSet(author: "mg (generated)", id: "1437215773652-2") {
        createIndex(indexName: "id_uniq_1437215773559", tableName: "city", unique: "true") {
            column(name: "id")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is by Database configureate. I also use hibernate spatial dialect:

```
dataSource {
  pooled = true
  jmxExport = true
  driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  username = "sa"
  password = ""
}
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = false
  cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3

  singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
  flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
  development {
    dataSource {
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
      username = "root"
      password = ""
      dialect = org.hibernatespatial.mysql.MySQLSpatialInnoDBDialect
      pooled = true
      properties {
        maxActive = -1
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
        numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
        testOnBorrow=true
        testWhileIdle=true
        testOnReturn=true
        validationQuery = "select 1"
      }
    }
  }
  test {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update"
      url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    }
  }

}
```

Then I run ``grails dbm-update```which leads to the following error:

```
|Starting dbm-update for database root @ jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
Error |
2015-07-18 12:41:10,184 [main] ERROR liquibase  - Change Set Update4.groovy::1437215773652-1::mg (generated) failed.  Error: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE `city` (`id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `version` BIGINT NOT NULL, `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `last_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `cityPK` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) type=InnoDB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
Message: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE `city` (`id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `version` BIGINT NOT NULL, `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `last_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `cityPK` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) type=InnoDB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
    Line | Method
->>   62 | execute           in liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    104 | execute           in     ''
|   1091 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase
|   1075 | executeStatements in     ''
|    317 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet
|     27 | visit             in liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor
|     58 | run . . . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator
|    114 | update            in liquibase.Liquibase
|     26 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2
|     59 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11
|    133 | executeInSession  in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     51 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2
^     25 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1
Caused by MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
->>  400 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    383 | getInstance       in     ''
|    980 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   3847 | checkErrorPacket  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   3783 | checkErrorPacket  in     ''
|   2447 | sendCommand       in     ''
|   2594 | sqlQueryDirect .  in     ''
|   2541 | execSQL           in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2499 | execSQL . . . . . in     ''
|    844 | execute           in com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl
|    748 | execute . . . . . in     ''
|     92 | doInStatement     in liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback
|     55 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor
|    104 | execute           in     ''
|   1091 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase
|   1075 | executeStatements in     ''
|    317 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet
|     27 | visit             in liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor
|     58 | run . . . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator
|    114 | update            in liquibase.Liquibase
|     26 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2
|     59 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11
|    133 | executeInSession  in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     51 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2
^     25 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set Update4.groovy::1437215773652-1::mg (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE `city` (`id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `version` BIGINT NOT NULL, `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `last_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `cityPK` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) type=InnoDB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1:
          Caused By: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE `city` (`id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `version` BIGINT NOT NULL, `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `last_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `cityPK` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) type=InnoDB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1:
          Caused By: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:347)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:27)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:58)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:114)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(DbmUpdate:26)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:59)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:51)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmUpdate:25)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE `city` (`id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `version` BIGINT NOT NULL, `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `last_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `cityPK` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) type=InnoDB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:104)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.execute(AbstractDatabase.java:1091)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractDatabase.java:1075)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:317)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:92)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    ... 12 more
```

**What causes this error and how can I prevent it?**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-innodb-tables.html. try running CREATE TABLE `city` (`id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `version` BIGINT NOT NULL, `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `last_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `cityPK` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) type=InnoDB: in your mysql console. Looks like type should be engine

Comment: I don't get it. Please be more specific?

Comment: Review the answer below, what I was saying is that in your above error message it gave back actual mysql statement it was trying to carry out and was complaining about type=InnoDB. The initial link provided shows that it should be engine=InnoDB so below  I have manually executed your query then changed to what it should be. Unsure what is generating that statement but the issue is this.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to give this as an answer to make output more clear:

First attempt with the SQL command as per above in your error message:

```
    mysql> CREATE TABLE city (id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, version BIGINT NOT NULL, date_created DATETIME NOT NULL, last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT cityPK PRIMARY KEY (id)) type=InnoDB;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
```

Now lets change type=InnoDB to engine=InnoDB and run again:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE city (id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, version BIGINT NOT NULL, date_created DATETIME NOT NULL, last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT cityPK PRIMARY KEY (id)) engine=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.46 sec)
```

Presto it worked.

For some reason the SQL generated create statement should be engine=InnoDB and not type=InnoDB.

Comment: I changed the dialect to ``dialect = org.hibernatespatial.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect`` and it also worked. But what dis the difference?